# Make DelayedJob synchronous in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

How to make DelayedJob not pushing the job in the database but perform them synchronously on development environment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of DelayedJob 2.1.3 you can use `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false` in an initializer.

You can also check for an ENV variable setting to make it possible to force jobs to be asynchronous in development :

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = Rails.env.production? || ENV['DELAYEDJOB'].present?
```